# if sql clause and sql conditions then is dynamic sql the best way to go?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm been given a task at work that involves running sql queries for a search page in a Application that queries different numerous Documents (i.e.Offers, Invoices, Sales Contracts, Sales Orders, Pick Lists, etc. ) based on numerous parameters ( document creation date ranges, end customers in question, status values of documents, etc. ).

The sql select clause component, and the sql condition component will really be vary ( i.e. Dynamic ) based on how the Web user enters values into the search page.

Everything seems to suggest that I implement the solution using Dynamic SQL which I really Don't like.

I was also thinking about Building the sql query within C# using String Builder but wouldn't that be worse in terms of speed performance.

Could someone please suggest any other method of doing so?

Comment: Why not Entity Framework or some other ORM?

Comment: ORMs like Entity Framework would require approval from my management, and also ORMs might make speed performance slower.

Comment: Why do you need to vary the select clause? Just `select *` and filter on the client. You can probably write a single sproc with a where clause like `where (@param1 is null or table.param1=@param1) and (@param2 is null or table.param2=@param2) and ...`

Comment: Slower compared to what? You also need to consider development vs runtime speed.

Comment: Sounds to me like a typical catch-all query. There are few ways to handle this. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 2):

If you are going the traditional SQL route and if your list of possible parameters is known at coding-time, but many are optional, this can still be accomplished without dynamic SQL.  For example.

```
(@BeginDate Is Null or Document.BeginDate>=@BeginDate) And (@EndDate Is Null or Document.EndDate<=@EndDate) And (@CustomerId Is Null or Document.CustomerId=@CustomerId) And (@DocumentStatus Is Null or Document.Status=@DocumentStatus)
```

Comment: So, if you need one condition OR another, you need yet another sproc. And if you need two AND and one OR you need yet another sproc, and so on, and so forth

Comment: The problem is that the select clause can also really vary based on Web user's input entry in the search webpage.

Comment: Yes, this approach would not be suitable for a full "custom query logic" implementation - but most search pages I've seen just provide a list of optional fields that get ANDed together.

Comment: Here is a deeper explanation as to why this type of approach works but doesn't scale well. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: I've had success with the approach...granted i work more with oracle than with SQL server...as far as the Or comment...you would join two result sets...keep in mind ANY dynamic solution won't have optimal performance because the database engine won't have a known explain plan to rely on with good stats to back it up

Comment: @Ctznkane525 not entirely true. As long as your dynamic SQL still uses parameters, there won't be too many unique queries, and SQL Server (at least) will end up with a cached plan for each.